# In AngularJS 1.x, if two directives both depend on a service object, should both directives set a watch on that service object?

Tags: angularjs

In AngularJS 1.x, if two directives both set and read values from a service object, should both directives set a watch on this service object?

Another developer kept on saying she will set values into the object, and will not set a watch on it.  On the other hand, another directive may delete the key in this service object (which is the shopping cart content, such as

```
{ 
  shirt: { productID: 123, quantity: 1}, 
  jeans: { productID: 234, quantity: 2}
}
```

and then the first directive will not be able to react to this change (because there was no watch on it).  But instead, the other developer kept on saying that the other directive should not just delete the key in the service object, but should change the quantity first, and then delete the key.

(note that the `{ productID: 123, quantity: 1}` is not an object literal, but is a reference to an entry of array of items, such as `arrItems[32]`).

That's because by changing the quantity, her two-way binding can be triggered to updating her directive and UI display.

So she maintained that, her directive should not set a `$watch` on this service object.  All other directives should not just delete the key in the shopping cart content service object -- all other directives need to set the quantity to 0, before deleting the key.

So what that developer meant was, if the service object is

```
{ 
  shirt: { productID: 123, quantity: 1}, 
}
```

then her directive will still show "jeans" as quantity 2, and she refused to change her directive so that it will watch on this service object.

All these items came from an API, so there can be 30 items, and her directive actually add the key and reference to the item to the cart service object, and she added a quantity to have two-way binding with the UI.

Now the cart is the single reliable data object that says what the user has chosen to purchase.  So, by deleting the key in the service object, it is the accurate indication that the user did not choose to buy any of this item.

It also is the most basic principle that, when there are multiple components (or directives) that need to set and read from this single data source, you should set it, and also set yourself as an observer, for any data change of this object.

Therefore, shouldn't all directives that set and read from this service object set a watch on the object to observe for the changes, instead of having other directives needing to set some low level values for you, just for your directive to work?

Comment: How does setting the quantity to zero help other directive to detect the change without a `$watch`?

Comment: I think because she used two-way binding with the quantity and the UI... so her UI should have something with `ng-model` with the `quantity`, and the `quantity` is something on the `scope`, such as `scope.arrItems`

Comment: Then if another directive deletes an item, wouldn't her directive see the quantity change to `undefined`?

Comment: no, because her directive is two-way bound to `arrItems[32]`.  It is not two-way bound to the cart object

Answer (score 2):

*This is more of a design decision, maybe more appropriate to programmers.se, but so be it.*

Let's say that you want to remove an item from the cart. As you said, there are two ways: 1)delete the object 2) set the object's `quantity` property to 0.

Are those two semantically the same? Is it possible that you want *zero* of something in your cart? Imho, no, setting a quantity to zero, means that I don't want to purchase any of that item. So they're different ways to implement the same intent from the end user.

Which one should you prefer? If the GUI works better with setting the quantity to 0, do that. Imo, it's an argument caused by the lack of separation of concerns. You have two different objects, manipulating the same data. Only one thing in your Angular app should be able to modify the state of your cart, and both directives should ask that object to remove an item/mutate the cart's state. I'm guessing that's what your service does.

(*For example, provide a function `setQuantity()` and `remove()` and call whichever you want, from either directive, the object that handles the cart's state must do the same thing if you ask it to set the quantity to 0 or remove the item.)*

---

If that's the case, then yes, every directive, **must** watch for changes in the service (or you can use events to notify them, but that's usually worse), as this is the best way to make sure that the data you are presenting through your directive is always up to date. If the other directive's designer requires that the quantity is set to 0 before the key being deleted (it might be a code smell), then make sure that the service sets the quantity to 0 before deleting the property.

Comment: It is the cleanest to delete the key, because the 2nd directive actually display all items and its quantity (and together with a category heading).  Also, when you check out, you also have to filter out all items in the cart that has quantity of 0?  It is just cleanest to have the cart delete the key

Comment: by the way, the service object has no function at all.  It merely is a pure data store

Comment: That's how I would also think, but because I don't know how that directive is coded, and since its dev told you that it is a requirement that the quantity is first set to zero, I wouldn't deviate from that. If you think that this makes little sense (which is very reasonable), then verify why (or if) it is indeed required by that directive, by reading its code.

Comment: if my cart service object is `{ shirt: { productID: 123, quantity: 1} }` and you are telling me that oh no, the UI will still show "jeans" as quantity 2, that to me, is really stupid.

Comment: By adding getters and setters to the service, you can make sure that no user of the service, mutates it to an invalid state. If you're writing all the code and no one else in the future might maintain it, you can get away with writing directly on the data.

Comment: I agree, but I don't know what the directive does. The reasonable/obvious thing is to iterate over the service with `ng-repeat` and show quantities etc. If you do that, by removing the `jeans` you're ok. But I don't know how it's done.

Comment: it is never an invalid state.  Even with getter and setter, it will still be `{ shirt: { productID: 123, quantity: 1} }` and her UI will still show jeans as quantity 2 because she doesn't want to set a watch on the cart object

Comment: Her directive is: a box with "Jeans and then a minus and a plus button, and a text input box to change the quantity" and this directive sets values into the cart object and is also supposed to reflect what the cart contains back to this directive and UI

Comment: Indeed, I was just speaking generally. This is a very simple case, but maybe if you have a `laptop: {color:"red",ssd:"128gb"}` and you directly modify the color to "blue", maybe that's an invalid state, since blue laptops can only have a 512gb ssd. *bad example*

Comment: From what you're saying, maybe she's done something wrong that seems to work but it is a bug (for example it updates the quantities and new items, but if you remove the jeans it still shows them).